# Three.js cant see corner of cubes

Tags: javascript, three.js, react-three-fiber

I created an `Orbital Controls` with a `boxGeometry` to render a box. However, when I zoom to my desired distance from the box, the corners of the box do not get rendered like so:

[image]

I am currently using `react-three-fiber` and `react-three-drei`

```js
const SceneItems = () => {
    return (
        <>
            <OrbitControls
                minDistance={0.001}
            />
            <ambientLight intensity={0.5} />
            <spotLight position={[10, 15, 10]} angle={0.3} />
            <Cube />
        </>
    )
}

const CompleteScene = () => {
    return (
        <div id={styles.scene}>
            <Canvas
                camera={{ position: [0, 0, 0] }}
                orthographic={true}
            >
                <SceneItems />
            </Canvas>
        </div>
    )
}
```

I figured I could reduce the `minDistance` on the `OrbitalControls` but to no effect. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this counts as a complete answer, but for whatever reason when I remove the `camera` property in `<Canvas>` I am finally able to get the result that I want. I think since `<Canvas/>` provides a `perspectiveCamera` by default and I added the props there, it overrode my added `orbitalControls`.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[image]

- In this case, you have to decrease "near" property from PerspectiveCamera, ej. 0.1

[image]

- In this case, you have to increase "far" property from PerspectiveCamera

In this question, there is an perspective vs orthographic image
[From perspective picture to orthographic picture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36573283/from-perspective-picture-to-orthographic-picture)